# Include script only once

Tags: twig

I am building some twig modules that require specific javascript to work.

A javascript file is an asset that can be included as follows:

```
<script src="{{ asset('what/ever/hello.js') }}">
```

All cool so far, but knowing that:

- Those modules may or may not be present on the final rendered page.
- Those modules may appear more than once on the same page.
- I don't want to include the javascript in all pages, only when at least one instance of the module that requires it is present.

If I add the script to the module twig file, and if the module is used multiple times, it will result in my page containing multiple calls to the same script.

How can I approach this case?

Comment: Instead of adding the `script` tag in each seperate template, consider adding the asset to an array, make the array unique, loop out and add assets

Comment: `at least one instance of the module that requires it is present` - I mean, there is no magic way to detect this, how are you adding/determining wether a module is added or not?

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks for your attention. The way I see this, is to be able to have access to some kind of global variable so that I can have, in each module something like `if globalValueModuleAlreadyIncluded is false --> include script and set globalValueModuleAlreadyIncluded to true` so that the second time this is reached, it won't be included again.

Comment: You mean you would add the code above in a template file right or is this something you want to do in your controller?

Comment: @DarkBee Exactly, I would add it to the Twig block itself. For example, special-form.twig would contain this "code", and if the special-form.twig gets called from another parent twig template, it would include the script. If for some reason it was called twice, the script would only be included the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with an extension to keep track of the scripts you want included,

```php
<?php
    class Project_Twig_Extension extends \Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension {
        protected $scripts = [];

        public function getFunctions() {
            return [
                new \Twig\TwigFunction('get_scripts', [ $this, 'getScripts']),
                new \Twig\TwigFunction('add_script', [ $this, 'addScript']),
            ];
        }

        public function getScripts() {
            return $this->scripts;
        }

        public function addScripts($script) {
            if (!in_array($script, $this->getScripts()) $this->scripts[] = $script;
        }
    }
```

---

Just some mock-up modules

```html
{% do add_script('modules/module_a.js') %}
<h1>Module A</h1>
```

```html
{% do add_script('modules/module_b.js') %}
<h1>Module B</h1>
```

---

Just a simple base template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% for script in get_scripts() %}
            <script src="{{ asset(script) }}"></script>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Just a simple child template

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% incude "modules/module_a.html" %}
    {% incude "modules/module_b.html" %}
    {% incude "modules/module_a.html" %}
    {% incude "modules/module_b.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

This would output something like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Module A</h1>
        <h1>Module B</h1>
        <h1>Module A</h1>
        <h1>Module B</h1>

        <script src="js/modules/module_a.js"></script>
        <script src="js/modules/module_b.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this goes well beyond of what I expected!